# Подпорка под дерево

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жерди, подпирающие дерево - это козлы, подпорки?

Comment: Кόзлы это совсем не то. Козлˊы тем более.

Answer (score 1):

Для фиксации саженцев деревьев применяются подпорки, колышки, распорки, растяжки, ограды, заборчики.

Answer (score 1):

О формулировке: *Жерди, подпирающие дерево, — это козлы, подпорки?*
После слова "дерево" необходимо поставить запятую (она закрывает причастный оборот).

О жердях: это [колья](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=SIEvKDC5aBY-BM%252CbQzl7dQndHwpuM%252C_%253B_6nCvZ5tj_EtiM%252COpKJCT3BNTy6ZM%252C_%253BlP4NSLEKYddIaM%252CciQ2OaQEatGLyM%252C_%253BcqpP71tZQmElfM%252ClXOkm97tiQFnBM%252C_%253BVOZA8uyqfzGGjM%252CnMaDTSu0C_8-wM%252C_%253B2MbP3O26-LUDFM%252Ce1C30g5OCVTKmM%252C_%253Btzs7cJKWdd1qAM%252C9AuOtVERp5mNNM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kR2oYmXxQywKzq_gH0xKu-lVN16vA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiVvMCVy4PwAhWBsaQKHUlNByAQ9QF6BAgJEAE&biw=1366&bih=600#imgrc=ioukTpOQFwarUM).

О самой конструкции: я бы назвала ее треножником (или треногой).

В толковом словаре Кузнецова:
[трено́жник](https://endic.ru/kuzhecov/Trenozhnik-73084.html)
Подставка на трёх ножках; приспособление различного назначения из трёх палок, жердей и т. п., соединённых наверху.
[трено́га](http://www.endic.ru/kuzhecov/Trenoga-73081.html)
**1.** *Разг.* = Трено́жник.

[Опора для саженцев и фиксаторы](https://gilass.com.ua/intensivnui-sad/opora-dlya-sagencev-i-ficsatoru/)